# How to invoke my custom decoder in android source code

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-mediaplayer, android-framework, stagefright

I am trying to add my software HEVC decoder to android source code. I wish to generate the **libstagefright.so** file.

I have referred to other similar questions and were not of much help for me. I was not able to get a clear picture with the following questions or the reference guide.

1)Integrating a Codec to Android multimedia framework.

2)Integrate a custom decoder to play on android and display fps at the same time.

3)How to register a OMX core for adding a new decoder.

Can someone please help me with the steps for integration of a new custom decoder with Android.

Right now, I have just added the  to media_codecs.xml and `{ "OMX.google.h265.decoder" , "hevcdec" , "video_decoder.hevc" }` in SoftOMXPlugin.cpp file.

Which other files need to be edited for a new format to be added to android source code?
Which functions invoke my decoder source code(Does the softomxcplugin source file invoke my decoder ?).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From your query and earlier discussions, please find the steps to integrate a `HEVC` component into `Android` framework. Since, your component is a `SW` component, you would have to integrate the same as a `SoftVideoDecoderOMXComponent`.

**What is `SoftVideoDecoderOMXComponent`?**

In the latest releases of the `Android` `Stagefright` framework, `SW` accelerated codecs are integrated into the framework using an `OMX` like interface. Earlier, this wasn't the case and had some challenges of it's own. So, Google have streamlined the integration strategy and mandated that all `SW` codecs will employ a `SoftOMXComponent` like interface.

Majority of the `OMX IL` calls are handled by the base class and hence, the implementation of a new codec component is relatively easy as described below.

I would take the example of `AVC` codec integration to provide an overview. It is **highly recommended** that the reader is familiar with [`OMX IL` 1.1.2 specification](https://www.khronos.org/registry/omxil/specs/OpenMAX_IL_1_1_2_Specification.pdf) which describes the structure, functioning and state machine of an `OMX IL` video decoder component.

**Note:** `HEVC` is not yet a part of `OMX IL` specification and hence, the recommendation is mainly to understand the structure and functioning of the component.

**Creation of `SoftHEVC` component**

Please refer to the header file of [`SoftAVC.h`](http://androidxref.com/4.4.2_r1/xref/frameworks/av/media/libstagefright/codecs/on2/h264dec/SoftAVC.h) and the corresponding source [`SoftAVC.cpp`](http://androidxref.com/4.4.2_r1/xref/frameworks/av/media/libstagefright/codecs/on2/h264dec/SoftAVC.cpp).

You will have to implement a similar set of files. It is highly recommended to reuse the overall implementation from `AVC` due to some inherent similarities.

**`SoftHEVC.cpp` implementation**

1. You would have to define a `SoftHEVC` component in `SoftHEVC.h` which derives from `SoftVideoDecoderOMXComponent`. This would ensure that all `OMX` calls are handled suitably by the base class.
2. You would have to define a table of support `profile`-`level` combinations as found in [`CodecProfileLevel`](http://androidxref.com/4.4.2_r1/xref/frameworks/av/media/libstagefright/codecs/on2/h264dec/SoftAVC.cpp#31).
3. In the `constructor`, you can initialize most of the variables in a similar fashion. Since this is a video decoder component, you will have to initialize 2 ports viz.,`input` and `output`. `ctor` invokes a `initDecoder` to initialize the component. You would also have to implement a similar functionality for your codec.
4. The `dtor` is self explanatory and hence, I will skip explaining the same.
5. `onQueueFilled` is invoked when a buffer filled with a frame worth of bitstream data is provided for processing on `input` port or a free buffer is provided for `output`. This invokes the main decoding function [`H264SwDecDecode`](http://androidxref.com/4.4.2_r1/xref/frameworks/av/media/libstagefright/codecs/on2/h264dec/SoftAVC.cpp#154). Now, for the first frame, you could encounter a change in resolutions as compared to the originally initialized resolution. This is handled by 2 scenarios as described in the next point.
6. You would observe 2 functions `handlePortSettingsChanged` and `handleCropRectEvent`. These 2 events are important from an output buffer's perspective. **`handlePortSettingsChanged`** signifies a **change in the output buffer dimensions** as compared to the originally initialized size and hence, provides an event callback to the user to free up the current allocation and reallocate the same.
   **`handleCropRectEvent`** indicates that the __cropping window__which is communicated to the user. Usually, this doesn't require a buffer reallocation.
7. [`drainOneOutputBuffer`](http://androidxref.com/4.4.2_r1/xref/frameworks/av/media/libstagefright/codecs/on2/h264dec/SoftAVC.cpp#258) will copy the decoded frame onto the output port's buffer and [notify the caller about the availability](http://androidxref.com/4.4.2_r1/xref/frameworks/av/media/libstagefright/codecs/on2/h264dec/SoftAVC.cpp#272) of the decoded buffer.
8. In `onQueueFilled`, after a successful decode, the [input buffer which has been consumed is also returned back](http://androidxref.com/4.4.2_r1/xref/frameworks/av/media/libstagefright/codecs/on2/h264dec/SoftAVC.cpp#200) to the caller.
9. The rest of the functions are very straightforward and I feel you could simply reuse majority of the implementation.
10. For registration of the component, you will have to implement `createSoftOMXComponent` which creates the `SoftHEVC` component as shown [here](http://androidxref.com/4.4.2_r1/xref/frameworks/av/media/libstagefright/codecs/on2/h264dec/SoftAVC.cpp#322).

Since, you have already handled the registered the component, I am skipping that part. Just for reference, I presume you have registered the component in [`kComponents`](http://androidxref.com/4.4.2_r1/xref/frameworks/av/media/libstagefright/omx/SoftOMXPlugin.cpp#36) array in `SoftOMXPlugin`. Also, since `HEVC` is not a known `MIME` type, you would have to register the same. There would be a change required in `MediaDefs.cpp` where you will have to introduce a new entry, `MEDIA_MIMETYPE_VIDEO_HEVC` similar to existing formats like `AVC` and support changes in `OMXCodec.cpp` and `ACodec.cpp`.

With these steps, I presume you should be able to integrate your `SW` decoder and be able to realize your playback.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I followed the steps you provided and was able to generate libstagefright_hevc_decoder.so. Now, I am not sure whether my software decoder has perfectly integrated. I am trying to look for options for testing the libstagefright file before testing on tablet. I would be grateful, if you can help me with the steps to integrate libstagefright with my hardware like does the hardware needs to be flashed/formatted.

Comment: @sayedjuned.. How does your stream look? Is it an elementary stream or in container format? If it's container format, you can use the inbuilt `stagefright` executable to test it? If its an elementary stream, we will have to rebuild a new `stagefright` executable, capable of handling the same. These steps dont guarantee a display on the screen and if you are interested in the same, then you will have to test it with a `MediaPlayer`. Please share which of the paths you would like to verify

Comment: my stream is an elementary stream and I would like to display the video on the device. Could you please let me know the changes required for the libstagefright executable for testing the elementary stream.

Comment: @sayedjuned.. My honest feedback would be to embed this into a `MP4` file as the amount of changes required would be very limited and some of them offline. To integrate an elementary stream player into existing `Stagefright` framework, there is a lot of effort required. I feel its better to try with container format.

Comment: Thanks for your reply As per your feedback container format seems much more easier. But I am not familiar with any container format. I would be glad if you can guide me  with the steps to integrate my decoder to any container format. Could you please suggest any container format that can be accessed and changed easily as I am falling short of time.

Comment: @sayedjuned.. I had already recommended `MP4` file format as this is the most common format. There are a lot of free tools available including `FFMPEG` which can help you wrap your elementary stream into a container format.

Comment: I am thankful for your suggestion regarding FFMPEG. At this point, I am a little bit confused with the current concept and new suggestion of integrating with FFMPEG. I find you very knowledgeable and experienced in the field of Android. I will be very thankful if you can share me your email ID or skype ID, so that we can converse with each other better and there is no communication gap between us. If you can oblige with this request, my email address is sjchagan@gmail.com.